# unable to install git from sources on ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, debian

I have the issue on ubuntu16.04 when I install deb package after checkinstall.

I have the same issue also on debian9 and ubuntu18.04

On UBUNTU 14.04 and Centos7 I have installed git from sources without problems.

---

```
$ wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/snapshot/git-2.16.2.tar.gz

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev asciidoc xmlto docbook2x

$ make configure

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local

$ make all

$ sudo checkinstall --install=no

$ sudo dpkg -i git_2.16.2-1_amd64.deb
```

> Selecting previously unselected package git.
>   (Reading database ... 209500 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack git_2.16.2-1_amd64.deb ...
>   **Unpacking git (2.16.2-1) ...
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git:
>    libcgi-pm-perl (4.38-1) breaks git (<< 1:2.1.3) and is installed.
>     Version of git to be configured is 2.16.2-1.**
>
> dpkg: error processing package git (--install):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.2-1) ...
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    git

**And after it I can't upgrade**

> $ sudo apt-get upgrade
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
>   **The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libcgi-pm-perl : Breaks: git (< 1:2.1.3)
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**

I did 'apt-get --fix-broken install' but it didn't help

**Who knows what's the problem?
Thanks for help.**

Comment: I have removed some libraries: libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libparse-debianchangelog-perl lintian  and NOW THATs OKAY.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install git`

In case of errors, follow step 3 and 4

3. `sudo apt-get install -f`
4. `sudo apt-get install git`

Refer this [Digital Ocean Git installation link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-14-04). You can also optionally install [linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/) and use it to install git.

Comment: I need to install from sources. I've written about it in HEADing